# Interrupt Script in Windows

Tags: windows-7

In Ubuntu when running a script of some kind from the CLI I can press Ctrl+C to interrupt or Ctrl+Z to sleep that script. Is there an equivalent function in Windows 7? Those keys don't work in Windows and all of my googling reveals how to interrupt with code inside a bash script which isn't what I need.

Comment: Specifically which kind of script are you running?  Does CTRL-C not work form ANY (kind) of script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is indeed the standard way to interrupt the running of a command line script, in Windows 7 too. This is confirmed by [**21 Command Prompt Tricks and Hacks**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/tp/command-prompt-tricks-hacks.htm).

According to [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C), the usage stems from CP/M.

Comment: [And `Control`+`Break` of course.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682541(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I went to go try it again after reading that and it worked. No idea what was going on, after a year of wishing that it worked... it suddenly does. Thanks for the response.